# Помощь с выводом таблицы в реальном времени и проверки значений

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, node.js, rest

Очень нужна помощь и советы по реализации. Имеется административная панель с одной таблицей, с выводом последних 60 строк из MySQL базы. В базу поступают каждые несколько секунд от 1-10 записей, а так же в каждой записи может обновиться 1 ячейка. В админ панели находятся 3 менеджера, которые работают между собой. Собственно вопросы

1. Как реализовать обновление данных в реальном времени с учетом проверки на обновления ячеек у последних 60 строк, так чтобы каждая новая строка или обновление ячейки строки выделялось на несколько секунд (чтобы зрительно видеть изменения) ?
2. Какими  технологиями реализовать функцию выбора строки для каждого менеджера, т.е. при появлении новой строки, один из менеджеров может нажать на кнопку "принял", и у остальных появится небольшой блок рядом со строкой и именем менеджера (предполагал на node.js и socket.io сделать, но не знаю как совместить с php), данные не нужно сохранять в таблицу, они будут храниться в сессии

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Вам достаточно тут и ajax

Comment: @Manitikyl, а подскажите, как правильно организовать проверку значений изменений определенного столбца из последних выведенных строк?

Comment: Строите объект где ключами являются какие нибудь id записей на экране. бежите по массиву пришедших данных, если id в объекте нет - это новая строка, добавляете ее куда нибудь (только пока не в этот объект). Если строка есть - сверяете данные, если изменились, отражаете этот факт. после чего этот ключ из объекта удаляете. Когда массив входных данных закончился, смотрите объект - все ключи которые в нем остались, это те строки которых не было в новых данных - их можно удалять с экрана

Comment: @Mike вроде понял, спасибо